# 3D representation of A4 that preserves the unit ball

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, group-actions, geometric-group-theory

The subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ generated by the matrices $$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,,\hspace{10pt}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)\,, \hspace{5pt}\text{and}\hspace{5pt}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 -1 & -1 & -1 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
is isomorphic to $A_4$.

When acting on $\mathbb{R}^3$, this representation does not preserve the unit $3$-ball (i.e. map the unit $3$-ball into itself). Given a $\mathbf{v}=(x,y,z)$ such that $\left\lvert\left\lvert \mathbf{v} \right \rvert\right \rvert<1$, we either have $\left\lvert\left\lvert A\mathbf{v} \right \rvert\right \rvert=\left\lvert\left\lvert \mathbf{v} \right \rvert\right \rvert$ or, up to permutation of the coordinates, $$\left\lvert\left\lvert A\mathbf{v} \right \rvert\right \rvert=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+(x+y+z)^2}$$
which achieves a maximum of $\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$ on the unit $3$-ball.

Is there another representation of $A_4$ in $\operatorname{GL}_3\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ that *does* preserve the unit $3$-ball?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lord Shark the Unknown gave a fine answer. I want to supplement it with the following generalization.

Assume that you have a finite group $G$ acting on $V=\Bbb{R}^n$ by linear transformations. Let $(\ ,\ )$ be the usual inner product on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Let us define another bilinear form $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ on $V$ by taking the average:
$$
\langle x,y\rangle=\frac1{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}(gx,gy).
$$
The following are easy to see:

- $\langle\ ,\ \rangle$ is bilinear and symmetric.
- for all $x\in V$ we have $\langle x,x\rangle\ge0$ with equality only when $x=0_V$.
- $\langle gx, gy\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ for all $g\in G$ and all $x,y\in V$.

Therefore the new metric given to $V$ by this averaged is invariant under the action of the group $G$. Call the resulting inner product space $V'$. All this immediately implies that balls in $V'$ are stable under $G$.

But, the space $V'$ is really the space $V$, we only changed the metric. You can easily find an orthonormal basis of $V'$. Rewriting the matrices of $G$ w.r.t. such a basis results in orthogonal matrices, i.e. $G$ acts by distance and angle preserving transformations.

> You can turn any finite subgroup of $GL(n,\Bbb{R})$ into a distance preserving group (one that thus also preserves balls) by redefining "distance" in a suitable way.

---

Closing remarks:

- This can be generalized to complex matrices and Hermitian inner products with the obvious modifications.
- If a subspace $U$ of $V'$ is stable under $G$, then so is the orthogonal complement $U^\perp$ leading to Maschke's theorem.
- Averaging arguments FTW.

Comment: Your emphasized statement is weaker than what you prove. It preserves not only a distance, but a distance arising from an invariant scalar product.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Can I convert these into matrices that preserve the original distance? What would I do?

Comment: I tried computing $B=[\langle b_i, b_j \rangle]$ where $b_1=(1,0,0,0)^\intercal$, $b_2=(0,1,0,0)^\intercal$, and so on. Then I multiplied $BA$ for each generator $A$ given in question, but this does not come out right, nor does $B^{-1}A$ or $B^\intercal A B$ or any of that.

Comment: Also I try Grahm-Schmidt algorithm on the $b_i$ using that inner product but don't know what to do with the new vectors. Linear algebra was long ago.

Comment: @WQArielleCosette Unless I made a mistake the quadratic form preserved by the original group is $Q(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+yz+zx$. I, too, need to think it thru what to do with that :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Well, I did find a unit ball preserving representation for the group in this question,but I now have similar problem with a representation of $C_5\rtimes C_4$ in $\operatorname{GL}_4(\mathbb{R})$. So, I am still want to figuring out how to do it

Answer (score 3):

Take a regular tetrahedron inscribed in the unit ball. Work out the
coordinates of its vertices $P_1,\ldots,P_4$. Work out the matrix $R_i$
of a rotation with angle $2\pi/3$
about the axis $OP_i$ with $O$ the origin. Then the $R_i$
generate a copy of $A_4$ (you only need two of them) preserving the unit ball.